# How to use Paramiko getfo to download file from SFTP server to memory to process it

Tags: python, pandas, io, sftp, paramiko

I am trying to download a CSV file (in-memory) from SFTP using Paramiko and import it into a pandas dataframe.

```
transport = paramiko.Transport((server, 22))
transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

with open(file_name, 'wb') as fl:
    sftp.getfo(file_name, fl, callback=printTotals)
    df = pd.read_csv(fl, sep=' ')
```

The code below fails, telling me:

> OSError: File is not open for reading

I assume that I need some kind of buffer or file like object for `fl` instead, since open needs a file. I am relatively new to all of this, so I would be happy it if someone could help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple solution that still allows you to use progress callback is:

- Use [`BytesIO` file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) to store a downloaded file to memory;
- You have to seek file pointer back to file start after downloading it, before you start reading it.

  ```
  with io.BytesIO() as fl:
      sftp.getfo(file_name, fl, callback=printTotals)
      fl.seek(0)
      df = pd.read_csv(fl, sep=' ')
  ```

Though with this solution, you will end up having the file loaded to memory twice.

---

Better solution is to implement a custom file-like object. It will even allow you to download and parse the file at the same time.

```
class FileWithProgress:

    def __init__(self, fl):
        self.fl = fl
        self.size = fl.stat().st_size
        self.p = 0

    def read(self, blocksize):
        r = self.fl.read(blocksize)
        self.p += len(r)
        print(str(self.p) + " of " + str(self.size)) 
        return r
```

And use it like:

```
with sftp.open(file_name, "rb") as fl:
    fl.prefetch()
    df = pd.read_csv(FileWithProgress(fl), sep=' ')
```

*For the `SFTPFile.prefetch` call, refer to:

[Reading file opened with Python Paramiko SFTPClient.open method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58433996/850848)*.

---

If you do not need the progress monitoring, simple code like this will do:

```
with sftp.open(file_name, "rb") as fl:
    fl.prefetch()
    df = pd.read_csv(fl, sep=' ')
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for! I have found another solution in the mean time, which is not as good as I can't have a callback for reporting back the progress (see Answer below). Thank you!

Comment: @iamatsundere181 If you have a question, please post a new question with [mcve] and some evidences.

Answer (score 3):

What I ended up doing was a simple version of that, unfortunately without a callback for the progress, I also needed `rb` for reading:

```
with sftp.open(file_name, 'rb') as fl:
        df = pd.read_csv(fl, sep=' ')
```

Anyway, Martin's answer is what I was looking for!