# pysftp putfo creates an empty file on SFTP server but not streaming the content from StringIO

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, stringio, pysftp

My code first writes lines to a CSV in `io.StringIO()`:

```
fileBuffer = io.StringIO()

# write header
header_writer = csv.DictWriter(fileBuffer, fieldnames=columnNames)
header_writer.writeheader()

# write lines
writer = csv.writer(fileBuffer, delimiter=',') 

for line in data:
            line_dec = line.decode('ISO-8859-1') 
            # print([line_dec])
            writer.writerow([line_dec])
```

The following code also prints all expected rows:

```
$print(fileBuffer.getvalue())    # -> prints all expected rows
```

I can also successfully connect to the SFTP Server using pysftp and even in the with pysftp the code successfully returns all expected rows:

```
with pysftp.Connection(host, username=user, password=pw, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp: 
            print('sucessfully connected to {} via Port 22'.format(host))
            print(fileBuffer.getvalue())    # -> prints all expected rows
            sftp.putfo(fileBuffer, file2BeSavedAs)   # -> no rows put on FTP Server
```

**Here comes the actual problem:**
Unfortunately, the code only creates the file without writing the data respectively the body into it. On the other hand, my code does not return any error message.

**How can I put a CSV from `StringIO` to an SFTP server?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to seek a read pointer of the buffer back to the beginning, before you try to upload the buffer:

```
fileBuffer.seek(0)
sftp.putfo(fileBuffer, file2BeSavedAs)
```

---

Though a better approach is to write the CSV directly to the server, without an intermediate buffer. Use [`Connection.open`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.open) to obtain a file-like object representing a file on the SFTP server:

```
with sftp.open(file2BeSavedAs, mode='w', bufsize=32768) as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',') 
    # ...
```

For the purpose of the `bufsize` argument, see:
[Writing to a file on SFTP server opened using Paramiko/pysftp "open" method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58111798/850848)

---

For a similar question, with progress display, see:
[How to use Paramiko getfo to download file from SFTP server to memory to process it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50531631/850848)

---

Though pysftp is dead. You better use Paramiko. See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848). With Paramiko the code would be pretty much the same.