# How to put data into a tempfile and post as CSV on SFTP

Tags: python, csv, sftp, paramiko, temporary-files

**Goal is**

Create a temporary SCP file filled with data and upload it to an sftp. The data to fill is `TheList` and is from class `list`.

**What I am able to achieve**

- Create the connection to the SFTP
- Push a file to the SFTP

**What happens with the code below**

There is a file created/put to the SFTP, but the file is empty and has 0 byte.

**Question**

How can I achieve that I have a file with type SCP on SFTP with the content of `TheList`?

```
import paramiko
import tempfile
import csv

# code part to make and open sftp connection

TheList = [['name', 'address'], [ 'peter', 'london']]

csvfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.csv', mode='w', delete=False)
filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
filewriter.writerows(TheList)
sftp.put(csvfile.name, SftpPath + "anewfile.csv")

# code part to close sftp connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create a temporary file. You can use `csv.writer` to write the rows directly to the SFTP with use of file-like object opened using [`SFTPClient.open`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open):

```
with sftp.open(SftpPath + "anewfile.csv", mode='w', bufsize=32768) as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    filewriter.writerows(TheList)
```

See also [pysftp putfo creates an empty file on SFTP server but not streaming the content from StringIO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58434366/850848)

---

To answer your literal question: I believe you need to flush the temporary file before trying to upload it:

```
filewriter.flush()
```

See [How to use tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3924117/850848)

Though better option would be to use Paramiko [`SFTPClient.putfo`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.putfo) to upload the `NamedTemporaryFile` object, rather then trying to refer to the temporary file via the filename (what allegedly would not work at least on Windows anyway):

```
csvfile.seek(0)
sftp.putfo(csvfile, SftpPath + "anewfile.csv")
```

Comment: works as expected. Thank you