# Use pdfplumber and Paramiko to read a PDF file from an SFTP server

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I have a direct connection to an SFTP server – the connection works without any problem and I can display files from the selected directory without any major problem. There are different files on the server, I have several functions to read them and below here is a piece of code concerning `.pdf` files – I use `pdfplumber` to read PDF files:

```
# SSH.connect configuration

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

path = "/server_path/.."
for filename in sftp.listdir(path):
    fullpath = path + "/" + filename
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        #fullpath - full server path with filename - like /server_path/../file.pdf
        #filename - filename without path - like file.pdf
        with sftp.open(fullpath, 'rb') as fl:
            pdf = pdfplumber.open(fl)
```

in this `for` loop I want to read all the `.pdf` files in the chosen directory - and it works for me on the localhost without any problem.

I tried to solve it this way `with sftp.open(path, 'rb') as fl:` - but in this case this solution doesn't work and such an error code appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
pdf = pdfplumber.open(fl)
return cls(open(path, "rb"), **kwargs)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not SFTPFile
```

`pdfplumber.open` takes as an argument the exact path to the file with its name – in this case fullpath. How can I solve this problem so that it works directly from the server? How to manage the memory in this case – because I understand that these files are somehow pulled into memory. Please give me some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paramiko [`SFTPClient.open`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open) returns a file-like object.

To use a file-like object with `pftplumber`, it seems that you can use [`load` function](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#loading-a-pdf):

```
pdf = pdfplumber.load(fl)
```

*You will also want to read this:

[Reading file opened with Python Paramiko SFTPClient.open method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58433996/850848)*

---

As the Paramiko file-like object seems to work suboptimal when combined with `pftplumber.load` function, as a workaround, you can download the file to memory instead:

```
flo = BytesIO()
sftp.getfo(fullpath, flo)
flo.seek(0)
pdfplumber.load(flo)
```

See [How to use Paramiko getfo to download file from SFTP server to memory to process it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50531631/850848)